# everything is write protected in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 it's been a while using it. It worked great until I turned on my laptop this evening, booted into Ubuntu and wanted to make a C program for my friend and I realized that when I right click on my desktop to create a document file, it was grayed out. I can't even do it through terminal even after:

```
sudo su
gedit main.c
```

the same thing happens in every other directory. I cant even mount any partition. I searched on the internet and can't find any solution.

Comment: Did you login as guest?

Comment: no. I'm logged in as a user

Comment: I even tried using sudo aswell